# How to Replace a string taking an input from another file in Linux Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, replace

i have an existing users ID and wanted to change those IDs to users name
for e.g.

UserID.txt

```
Group1 = 1234,1002,2004
group2 = 3214,0032,6632
1234 = Read
6632 = Write
```

Input_file.csv

> search for column1 and replace with column2 from Input_file.csv

```
1234 onetofour
1002 ten2
2004 tennyfour
3214 threefouteen
0032 thirtytwo
6632 Sixtytwo
```

Using the Input_file.csv records, i want to replace IDs to names inside UsersID.txt

Expected Output:

```
Group1 = onetofour,ten2,tennyfour
group2 = threefouteen,thirtytwo,Sixtytwo
onetofour= Read
Sixtytwo = Write
```

I prefer shell scripting here, kindly suggest for the same.

Thanks

Comment: As this is not a free coding service, we'd appreciate seeing some attempt first. Don't post it as a comment, image, table or link to off-site service but use text and include it to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi James, i have already tried this manually on command line using sed.
it would be gr8 if U can suggest on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love bash and I had some free time.

```
bash-4.1$ cat UserID.txt
Group1 = 1234,1002,2004
group2 = 3214,0032,6632
1234 = Read
6632 = Write
bash-4.1$ data=$(cat Input_file.csv); awk '{print $1"/"$2}' <<<"$data" | xargs -I {} sed -i 's/{}/g' UserID.txt
bash-4.1$ cat UserID.txt
Group1 = onetofour,ten2,tennyfour
group2 = threefouteen,thirtytwo,Sixtytwo
onetofour = Read
Sixtytwo = Write
bash-4.1$
```

Comment: Thank U angshuman, i will try this and update :-)

Comment: I am able to achieve my goal, Thanx alot :-)